# Encoding issue with wkhtml2pdf footer-html/header-html parameters

Tags: character-encoding, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating PDF from HTML file using utf-8 encoding. As a matter of fact, some of my titles contain non-ascii characters. In main PDF, everything is fine, encoding is right, rendering is OK.

When setting my footer.html file, I retreive the current section which does not display right whenever there is a non-ascii character in section name.
This section name is passed as a "section" URL parameter to footer.html call ; its encoding is already wrong. For example, I changed my ToC titel to the french "Table des matières" in my xsl file (that's the only change made to default xsl).

ToC page is fine in PDF, the "è" is correct. But in my footer, I retreive URI via JS which give me **before** unencoding : `mati%C3%A8res` ( when I expected it to be `mati%E8res`), which of course displays in my PDF footer as `matiÃ¨res`

I've found numerous pages about encoding issues in templates, main html file or header/footer html file, none of them was related to these parameters. How can I make it right in PDF ?

Sample run :

```
F:\test>wkhtmltopdf.exe --encoding "UTF-8" --footer-html footer.html \
    --print-media-type toc --xsl-style-sheet default.xsl test.html test.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Loading TOC (3/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from my JS code. On parameters I used `unencode()` instead of using the correct function `decodeURIcomponent()`